# Trying to open a python file in IDLE. Instead, a pycache folder is created. How do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

I have a number of python files with .py extensions that I was working on, closed, and tried to come back to later. When I tried to open them by right clicking and selecting “Edit with IDLE,” instead of opening a pycache folder was created.

I have a work around in which I go to edit the file with Notepad++, copy the text into a new python editor, delete the old file, and resave the new file with the same name. My research has turned up questions related to pycache and IDLE, but none specifically addressing the issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem/know how to solve it? I’m running Python 3.5.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: I have not heard of anyone having a problem like this, so I would not be surprised if there is a problem with your Windows or Python.  Notes: 1. IDLE itself has nothing to do with the 'Edit with IDLE' code in Windows Explorer, except for being opened when the Explorer code works as intended. 2. IDLE has nothing to do with __pycache__.  It just asks Python to open a python file and python itself checks for the cached copy. 3. The best workaround is to open .py files from within IDLE using File => Open, File => Recent Files, or File => Open Module.  I seldom use Explorer for opening .py files.

Comment: More notes: 4. I keep IDLE pinned to the task bar to make it trivial to open. 5. If you can, upgrade to 3.5.3 (or even 3.6.0 or 3.6.1 when out in a couple of weeks).  I am pretty sure it has bug fixes for the Windows installer, and possibly to the 'Edit with...' code, both of which were rewritten for 3.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

What did you name the .py file as? If you named it something like "string.py", Python might interpret the file as one of those in the "Lib" folder. Why you can resave it with the same name and have it working afterwards is anyone's guess. I suggest just renaming the python file to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I developed the bad habit of writing/editing python files with IDLE from watching intro videos when I was still relatively new to programming. I have since learned that file editors like Sublime or IDE's like PyCharm are a significantly better way to go and would highly recommend anyone reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. When I clicked "Edit with IDLE 3.6", it would create a "pycache" folder and not open the python file on IDLE.

I found a Reddit thread that gives an explanation [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6c1t5m/sometimes_i_see_python_creates_pycache_folder/).

The reason the pycache folder is created is as follows:

> When you import a module, Python stores the compiled bytecode in that
>   directory so that future imports can use it directly, rather than
>   having to parse and compile the source again. It does not do that for
>   merely running a script, only when a file is imported.
>
> No such folder is created for the standard library, as the standard
>   library is pre-cached when you install Python

I was importing Python's "random" library, in another python file (placed in the same directory). So the issue was solved once I deleted that file.